# Sort python list by header order

Tags: python

I have a list of list, but the header is in random order(name, age, gender, nationality):

```
[['Name', 'gender', 'nationality','age'], #  (or any other order)
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
 ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'], 
 ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']]
```

My expected list order is Name, age, gender, nationality, and the details will go to the corresponding index.

```
[['Name', 'age', 'gender', 'nationality'], 
 ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'], 
 ['aa', 'cc', 'bb', 'dd'], 
 ['aaa', 'ccc', 'bbb', 'ddd']]
```

I tried to use code: sorted(zip(*data)),and so that to transport data to my expected output, but it doesn't seem to work, it only returns the first column's values.
[Name,'a','aa','aaa'].

Considering my data is a very huge list, more than 1500rows, I've tried the same code only implement to part of my data using code:sorted(zip(*data[:20)), it works perfectly fine, Just curious what could be the problem. And if there's other **plain python way** to sort this question other than zip(*data)function.

Cheers for any ideas:)

Comment: 1500 rows is not very huge. For reasonable row lengths, it fits on a floppy disk. Anyway, I know you asked for plain Python, but `pandas` makes this sort of stuff super easy.

Comment: I am not able to understand your description - if `['name', 'gender', 'nationality', 'age']` is `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` - then shouldn't `['name', 'age', 'gender', 'nationality']` be `['a', 'd', 'b', 'c']` ?

Comment: can you provide your current code?

Comment: @Mortz ,So sorry about the confusion and thanks for you modification. My current code is just as simple as :zip(*data), it wouldn't return other values except for first column.

Comment: @Thomas That's the reason I was so confused, since I've used the zip*function and tried to implement to this, surprisingly didn't work. I was trying to firgure the problem and just spotted it works fine for the sliced list of my full list. NO idea about what could cause this:(

Comment: @mozway My current code is just as simple as :zip(*data), it wouldn't return other values except for first column.

Answer (score 0):

You won't really have a choice but to transpose the data twice. You could use loops but `zip` is really the pythonic way to go.

Here is one option without sorting, using an intermediate dictionary and a double `zip`:

```
# inputs
l = [['Name', 'gender', 'nationality','age'], #  (or any other order),  
     ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
     ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'], 
     ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']]

order = ['Name', 'age', 'gender', 'nationality']

# create an intermediate dictionary of header: sublists
d = {k:v for k,*v in zip(*l)}
# {'Name': ['a', 'aa', 'aaa'],
#  'gender': ['b', 'bb', 'bbb'],
#  'nationality': ['c', 'cc', 'ccc'],
#  'age': ['d', 'dd', 'ddd']}

# reorder the headers
out = list(map(list, zip(*([k,*d[k]] for k in order))))
```

output:

```
[['Name', 'age', 'gender', 'nationality'],
 ['a', 'd', 'b', 'c'],
 ['aa', 'dd', 'bb', 'cc'],
 ['aaa', 'ddd', 'bbb', 'ccc']]
```